# Any way to get the position of an AcroField in PdfSharp without "/Rect"?

Tags: c#, pdf, pdfsharp

I am developing a program with C# and the library PDFSharp.
I am currently using the following code to get the X and Y coordinates of a specific AcroField in a PDF document:

```
PdfTextField imageField = (PdfTextField)inForm.Fields[elementName];
PdfRectangle rect = imageField.Elements.GetRectangle(PdfAnnotation.Keys.Rect);
```

This works fine if there is only 1 Field with the same name present in the PDF Document. However, if there are two fields both named "FirstName", even if they are on separate pages, this seems to remove the "/Rect" and "/P" flags, so I cannot use these to find the position or the page relevant to that field.

Is there any other way to get the position of a Field in the PDF, or any way to activate the "/Rect" and "/P" flags?

Thanks, RBrNx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What Mihai posted fits what I discovered from reverse engineering the PDF via PdfSharp. If there are multiple fields in the same document, they are nested under a parent container, and it is a reference to this parent container which PdfSharp will give you when using the AcroForm.Fields accessor. To get the Page and Rectangle elements for each field, you have to look at the children of that container.

To get the values you are looking for, you'll want to do something like this:

```
    PdfTextField imageField = (PdfTextField)inForm.Fields[elementName];
    var fieldRectangles = new List<PdfRectangle>();

    if( imageField.HasKids )
    {
      PdfArray kids = (PdfArray) Elements[Keys.Kids];
      foreach( var kid in kids )
      {
        var kidValues = ((PdfReference) kid).Value as PdfDictionary;
        var rectangle = kidValues.Elements.GetRectangle(PdfAnnotation.Keys.Rect);
        fieldRectangles.Add(rectangle);        
      }
    }
```

The page reference element ("/P" tag) is also available from these "Kid" elements.

Comment: This is almost exactly the code I ended up using! Except with the 1.50.4000 Beta3 Build of PdfSharp I managed to make it slightly shorter with

`if (imageField.HasKids)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < imageField.Fields.Elements.Count; ++i)
                    {
                        rect = imageField.Fields[i].Rectangle;
                        PdfPage page = imageField.Fields[i].Page;
                        DrawImage(inImagePath, page, rect);
                    }
                }`

Answer (score 2):

I'm not familiar with PDFSharp API but this is how it works in PDF: 
- form fields have document scope and not page scope. 
- 2 or more fields with the same name are in fact a single field with 2 or more widgets (widget annotations, the visual representation of a field). The /Rect and /P entries are stored at widget level. When the field has one widget, the widget is merged with the field so the /Rect and /P entries appear to be part of the field.

In your scenario you have to look for the /Kids key which is an array. Drill down through the /Kids array (a child can have his own kids and so on) till the last level where the /Kids is no longer present. At this level you should find the /Rect and /P keys.
Each widget can have its own /Rect and /P keys since they can appear on different pages at different positions.